# How to create a GUI with multiple JPanels

Tags: java, jpanel

> I have a basic layout for making a GUI like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZO5x.jpg) but i have no idea how to get the JPanels to do that. Can you give me an example or put me in the right direction?

Comment: did you try something ?

Comment: 10/10 paint example +1

Comment: Do you mean you need to know how to place the JPanels in that layout?

Comment: Yeah sorry Emd4600. Thats what i meant.

Comment: Try looking at this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html

Comment: Can't figure out anything from the [image](http://imgur.com/EeHI4mT) you provided. Can you be little more specific to the problem. Or provide a better image.

Comment: I did, it has nothing to do with multiple JPanels. I used BorderLayout and it looks like this. http://i.imgur.com/xHfwC76.png